# Using a variable from a one function in another function

Tags: c++, function, variables

I have made a code that calculates a shape. You enter the number of corners. Then the co-ords of each corners. From this it will give you the distance between each corner, the perimeter,area and centroid. I have got up to area and it can calculate it as e. but when I try to use "e" in centroid to calculate the xy co ords, it stops working. In the area i initialise e=0. in my centroid function, its taking e as 0 so when I try to divide 1 by "e", the program stops working.

```
void Area(int x[], int y[], int corners, int e, int g)
{
    e = 0; //Initialise e

    for (g = 0; g<(corners - 1); g++)
    {
        e += ((x[g] * y[g + 1]) - (x[g + 1] * y[g])); 
    }
    e += ((x[corners - 1] * y[0]) - (x[0] * y[corners - 1]));
    e *= -0.5;
    cout << "The Area is" << " " << e << endl;

}

void Centroid(int x[], int y[], int wx, int wy,int corners,int g,int e)
{
    wx = 0;
    wy = 0;

    for (g = 0; g < (corners-1); g++)
    {
        wx += ((x[g] + x[g + 1])*((x[g] * y[g + 1]) - (x[g + 1] * y[g])));
        wy += ((y[g] + y[g + 1])*((x[g] * y[g + 1]) - (x[g + 1] * y[g])));
    }

    wx *= ((1 / (6 * e)));
    wy *= ((1 / (6 * e)));

    cout << "The Centroid is" << " " << wx << "," << wy << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int g, corners, x[100], y[100], r[100], c, e,wx,wy;

     cout << "Enter the number of corners";
    cin >> corners;

    for (g = 0; g<corners; g++)
    {
        cout << "enter the co ordinates";
        cin >> x[g] >> y[g];
        cout << "You have entered " << x[g] << " " << y[g] << endl;
    }

    Distance(x, y, corners, r, c = 0);
    Perimeter(r, corners, g, c);
    Area(x, y, corners, e = 0, g,wx=00.0,wy=00.0);

    /*Centroid(x,y,wx=0,wy=0,corners,g,e);

    */

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The idea behind passing arguments to functions is that you calculate the value of each argument **before** passing it to the function. Otherwise, you might as well declare it as a local variable inside the function.

Comment: As @barakmanos said, you're passing parameters you don't need to pass. The variables `e`, `g`, `wx` and `wy` should all just be local `ints`.

Comment: And please show the code where you call these functions.

Comment: @CareyGregory Here's the code I call the function. I'm sorry if this isn't what you meant. I'm very new to c++ and we have to do this as part of our module. At this moment im trying to figure out what to do so I've commented out centroid.

Comment: Who's "we" and what is "our module"??

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to have your functions calculate values and return them. The point of the `Area` function is determine the area, and produce that as a result:

```
int Area(int[] x, int[] y, int corners) {
    int e = 0;

    for (int g = 0; g < corners - 1; ++g) { // g is local to this loop
        e += ((x[g] * y[g + 1]) - (x[g + 1] * y[g])); 
    }
    e += ((x[corners - 1] * y[0]) - (x[0] * y[corners - 1]));
    e *= -0.5;           

    return e; // give the caller the "answer"
}
```

That way, in your main, you can determine what `e` is there:

```
int e = Area(x, y, corners); // this function does not need g
```

And then pass that into your `Centroid` function:

```
int wx = 0, wy = 0;
Centroid(x, y, corners, e, wx, wy);
```

Where `Centroid`'s definition should look like:

```
void Centroid(int x[], int y[], int corners, int e, int& wx, int& wy)
```

We're taking `wx` and `wy` by *reference* so that we can return two values. Even better though would be to have `Centroid` return a `Point` object:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};
```

And have it compute the area itself:

```
Point Centroid(int x[], int y[], int corners) {
    Point p = {0};
    int e = Area(x, y, corners);
    // replace all code referencing wx and wy with p.x and p.y

    return p;
}
```

So that from `main`, the code looks even cleaner:

```
Point centroid = Centroid(x, y, corners);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use pointers or references to the variable.

You need to change your first line like this:

```
void Area(int x[], int y[], int corners, int &e, int g)
```

Comment: What is a "link"? I think you meant _reference_.

Comment: OK, I fixed that for you.